# Writing to Files : Printwriter Converting Forward Slash to Backslash

Tags: java, io, java-io, printwriter

Why is Printwriter doing this?

```
    File file = new File("/files/KA.txt");
    writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    writer.write("HELLO");
```

In the above code I keep getting an error that says :

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \files\KA.txt (The network path was not found)
```

Except this was not my specified path? How do I then specify a file to write - usually create a new file and write to this? It also throws errors if KA.txt is not present - I ideally want to create a new file and writer to it.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with `PrintWriter`, and everything to do with `File`. It's just canonicalizing the path.

Answer (score 1):

> I ideally want to create a new file and writer to it.

You can simply create a file ,

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("text");
```

where `UTF-8` is the file encoding. and write to the file , remember it overrides if the file exists with the same name

Comment: Yes but I want to add this file to a specific location within my project. Hence the use of forward slash?

Comment: You can do it like this `URL url = classLoader.getResource("path/to/folder");
File file = new File(url.toURI());`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parent /files directory doesn't already exist, so you must create it beforehand, using File.mkdirs.

```
    File file = new File("/files/KA.txt");
    File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
    parentFile.mkdirs();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    writer.write("HELLO");
    writer.close();
```